# Upgrading magento version

Tags: magento2.2.3

Currently, I have Magento version 2.2.0. I want to upgrade it to the version 2.2.3. What is the best way to achieve this? Could you please help me with simple steps to get it?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following method to upgrade Magento 2.x:

> cd to Magento root folder and run the following commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**Note:** In Ubuntu/Debian Linux, when you meet the permission issues, remember to insert sudo at the beginning of every command

> Now check the Magento version:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

If the system show the cache write permission error, please add the following command to give write permission to pub and var directories:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 pub var
```

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score -1):

- **Upgrade magento**
- composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
- composer update
- rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/*
- rm -rf var/di
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile(Optional)
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- chmod -R 777 var
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

  **After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:**
- php bin/magento --version

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below Answer

For example, to upgrade to Magento Open Source version 2.0.13, enter:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.13 --no-update
composer update
```

To upgrade to Magento EE version 2.0.13, enter:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.0.13 --no-update 
composer update
```

After the above command is been executed run magento 2 commands

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```